# update object inside array that is inside collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to update field "rightAnswer" in object inside array that is inside collection.

How can I change boolean of specific comment to true for right question.

In Angular I pass id of question and id of comment to backend. But on the backend I don't know how to update that field. I use MEAN stack.

Question schema:

```
var questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {type : String, default : '', trim : true},
    text: {type : String, default : '', trim : true},
    publisher_id: {type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'User'},
    answers: [{
        body: { type : String, default : '' },
        user: { type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'User' },
        rightAnswer: { type : Boolean, default: false },
        createdAt: { type : Date, default : Date.now }
    }],
    date  : {type : Date, default : Date.now}
});
```

My route in express:

```
  Question.update({_id: req.body.question._id}, {"answers._id": req.body.answer._id}, {$set: {"answers.$.rightAnswer": true} }, function(req, data){
    res.json(data);
  });
```

**Solution:**

```
Question.update({_id: req.body.question._id, 
                "answers": {$elemMatch: {_id: req.body.answer._id}}},
                {$set: {"answers.$.rightAnswer": true}}, 
                function(req, res){});
```

Comment: The positional update query would look like: `Collection.update({"_id":qId,"comments._id":commentId},{$set:{"comments.$.right":true}})`. But wait a minute, multiple sub documents in the `comments` array can have the same `_id` ?

Comment: I updated my question. Please take a look at it. I can't update my 'rightAnswer' to true.

Comment: Can you post a sample document from your collection? There seems to be a problem with identifying the `question` record.

Comment: Thank you. You might want to check if the `_id` passed is correct.

Comment: I did it's good. Updated question again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70667/discussion-between-batscream-and-vblazenka).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Question.update({_id: req.body.question._id, 
                "answers": {$elemMatch: {_id: req.body.answer._id}}},
                {$set: {"answers.$.rightAnswer": true}}, 
                function(req, res){});
```

Comment: Please edit your answer, and explain why this is a good solution.